# Are d3's reusable components objects?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When we call

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
```

are we instantiating a new axis object? I understand the `axis` component is implemented as a closure, but I am confused if it is also an object.

My question also applies to Mike's article Towards Reusable Charts, specifically the end of [this section](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/#reconfiguration). Using his pattern, if we do something like

```
var myChart = chart().width(720).height(80);
```

is `myChart` an object? If not, what is it? And what's the difference between doing this and doing `var myChart = new chart();`?

Comment: Since Javascript functions are also objects, the components would be objects too. And functions.

Comment: But, are they just `Object` objects, or are they also `chart` objects? i.e. is it equivalent to calling `new chart()`?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the two are equivalent, yes. What type of objects they are depends on your definition :) If you use the `instanceof` operator for example they would be e.g. `chart` objects, but Javascript has only a weak notion of a "class".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we're instantiating a new axis Object each time. This instance is a `function`, which in JavaScript is a first-class Object; meaning, you can assign properties to it like so:

```
function myFunc() {}
myFunc.foo = "bar";

myFunc();// This is possible (naturally)
console.log(myFunc.foo);// ...and this is valid too
```

If you wrapped the above code in a function:

```
function giveMeMyFunc() {
    function myFunc() {}
    return myFunc;
}
```

then every time you call

```
myFuncInstance = giveMeMyFunc();
```

you get a new instance of `myFunc` (which is also an Object), because `myFunc` is declared once per call.

So we've established that a function is also an Object. And, when a function returns another function it's as if it's returning a new instance of an Object, but being also a function, you could still call `myFuncInstance()`.

To drive the point home, and to perhaps answer your other questions, we can look at how `d3.svg.axis()` is actually implemented (loosely excerpted from the d3 source code):

```
d3.svg.axis = function() {
  /* Some variables here, which essentially are instance properties (protected through closure) */
  var scale = 123;
  ...

  /* This is a function, but since JavaScript functions are first-class objects, it's essentially an instance. */
  /* Each time (the outer) `d3.svg.axis()` is called, (the inner) `axis` function is a unique – not a shared – object. */
  function axis() {
    /* This is where the work of drawing the axis takes place, but won't get
      called until the axis is used (see below). */
  }

  /* Since the inner function `axis` is also an object, the following is an instance method */
  axis.scale = function(x) {
    scale = x;// here we're setting `scale`, which is basically an instance property

    // returning `axis` – a.k.a. our instance – is what enables method chaining: myAxis.scale(5).orient("left")
    return axis;
  }

  /* More methods here, like `axis.scale` above */

  /* Last line is very important: */
  /* This is where the newly created instance is return. Remember from */
  /* above, `axis` is a function, but it's an Object too, and it has the */
  /* methods we've just applied to it. */
  return axis;
}


/* Given all that, the line below returns an instance of `axis` (the inner function),
  which has more methods applied to it. */
myAxis = d3.svg.axis();
```

Finally, since the instance `myAxis` is also a function, you can call it. That's what d3 does when you apply an axis to a selection:

```
d3.select('.x_axis').call(myAxis);
```

D3 will call the `myAxis` function whose body, which is defined above in `function axis() {}` will do all the work of actually drawing some SVG stuff inside the element that matches the `'.x_axis'` selector.

Comment: Oh, and like Lars says, calling `new d3.svg.axis()` would (to the best of my knowledge) be the same as skipping the `new` BUT ONLY BECAUSE `axis` is being returned at the end of the function.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you so much for your response. Follow-up Q: I tend to think of JS objects as {} containers. That is, if I type `console.log(object)`, I'd see the word `Object`, which I could then expand, and it would show me all its props/methods. When I do that for this axis, or for a reusable chart, etc., I just get a function. Now, I understand that functions are objects (as are arrays, etc.), but why the difference? Why don't we see `Object`, and then expand it & see the function, in addition to its other props/methods?

Comment: I think it's just a "feature" of Chrome DevTools (or firebug, etc). Behind the scenes, `console.log` must be checking the type of the thing it's inspecting. Perhaps it's using `typeof foo == "function"` or `foo instanceof Function`, which evaluate to `true` if the instance was created the way that was described above, in which case it decides to print out the function's body rather than its properties. In my Chrome version it's possible to "trick" it into printing it in object format by wrapping the instance in a generic object: `console.log({ myObj: d3.svg.axis() })`.